# Spring Boot 3.0.0 X-Auth-Token gets deleted

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm migrating from Spring Boot 2.2.6 to Spring Boot 3.0.0 and I'm having issues with the authentication, with no changes in the configuration...

After authenticating, the redirect is throwing a AccessDenied, which encapsulates as InsufficientAuthenticationException...

```
  @Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable();
    http.headers().cacheControl().disable();
    http.headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin();
    http.headers().contentTypeOptions().disable();

    AuthorizeHttpRequestsConfigurer<HttpSecurity>.AuthorizationManagerRequestMatcherRegistry registry = http.authorizeHttpRequests();
    addPermissionToRegistry(registry, PUBLIC_URLS);
    addPermissionToRegistry(registry, USER_URLS, UserRole.USER.name());
    addPermissionToRegistry(registry, ADMIN_URLS, UserRole.ADMIN.name());
    registry.anyRequest().authenticated();
    http.formLogin().loginPage(BackendConstants.USER_PUBLIC_URL).permitAll(); //
    http.logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher(BackendConstants.LOGOUT_ENDPOINT)).invalidateHttpSession(true)
    .logoutSuccessUrl(BackendConstants.USER_PUBLIC_URL).permitAll(); //

    http.exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(customAccessDeniedHandler())
    .authenticationEntryPoint(new CustomLoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint());
    return http.build();
  }
```

Any ideas????

**Update 2022-12-23**

It is related with the header token being lost.
I'm setting it up with Javascript and the server doesnt get it.
When I use postman and I sent the header manually, the servlet works as expected...